# UDF with dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Trying to make it work .Df is dataframe and i need to add new column with UDF :

```
df = spark.sql("select 'foo' as tweet, 'bar' as medicine_name")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("medicine")

def similarity(x):
  return 'df_' + x
similarity_udf = udf(lambda z: similarity(z), returnType=StringType())

def main():

 distinct_df = spark.sql("select distinct medicine_name as medicine_name from medicine where medicine_name is not null")
 distinct_df.createOrReplaceTempView("distinctDF")

 df.show()


 result_df = df.withColumn('m_name', similarity_udf('tweet'))

 result_df.show()
```

but getting error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects/TestCase/main.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "PycharmProjects/TestCase/main.py", line 50, in main
    result_df.show()
  File "PycharmProjects\TestCase\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 350, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "PycharmProjects\TestCase\venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 933, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "PycharmProjects\TestCase\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "PycharmProjects\TestCase\venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Can anybody provide what is the problem?

Comment: can you add some sample data for your df ?

Comment: yes, sure. I updatetd my question.

Comment: i mean, some data. like what is the source ?

Comment: originaly it takes from database. 
but it falis  at result_df = df.withColumn('m_name', similarity_udf('tweet'))
too.

Comment: i tried your code with two columned data frame, and i couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: weird, so the problem not in the code? 
what did you import?

Comment: I think you have some null values in source.

Comment: i used this code i wrote in my question and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Comment: java version "9.0.4"